# publishing android apps on different markets

Tags: android, publish, google-play

i just have a question concerning publishing android apps 
can i publish my app in the android market and other markets like slideMe and andspot at the same time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. There is no restrictions on this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can post your apps in other market also.